# If/Else only works for first if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with this, but the issue is that only the first `if` ever functions correctly. If I change the order, each `if` statement works on its own, but the logic where if the first is false, then check the second, and so on isn't working. What am I missing here?

```
$("#search_button").click(function(){
    var table = $('#main_index').DataTable();
    var search_term = $("#second_select2 option:selected").text();
    var first_s = $("#first_select2 option:selected").text();
    if (first_s = 'District'){
        table.columns(1).search(search_term).draw();
    }
    else if (first_s = 'Territory'){
        table.columns(2).search(search_term).draw();
    }
    else if (first_s = 'Region'){
        table.columns(0).search(search_term).draw();
    }
    else {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

If I `console.log` the `search_term` and `first_s` variables, I can see them changing and correctly working. And, as I said, without the if/else statements each of these works on its own.

Comment: you are not comparing data in if condition rather you are assigning value in first_s

Comment: Use == instead of = to check for equality.

Comment: JS101: `=` is for *setting* a value, `==` or `===` is for *comparing* a value

Comment: in JavaScript there is a big difference between `=`, `==` and `===`

Comment: try to use triple equal to (===) to compare value with constants in jquery

Comment: Yoda would have fixed it in no time...  http://jsfiddle.net/we30rhtz/

Answer (score 5):

In all your comparisons, you need to replace `=` by `===`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator (`=`) in your comparisons. you should be using the identity operator: `===`.

Answer (score 1):

if (first_s = 'District'){

needs to be

if (first_s === 'District'){

as do the rest of the checks.